# How can I filter a multidimentional array for duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array set up like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [stage] => biometrics [applicant_id] => b79a4c6ea30611e3a3160675fe500303 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [stage] => biometrics [applicant_id] => b79a4c6ea30611e3a3160675fe600303 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [stage] => biometrics [applicant_id] => b79a4c6ea30611e3a3160675fe700303 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [stage] => biometrics [applicant_id] => b79a4c6ea30611e3a3160675fe800303 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [stage] => biometrics_queue [applicant_id] => b79a4c6ea30611e3a3160675fe900303 ) 
)
```

First, I want to check to see if there are any duplicate applicant_id's then I need to check the stages for the duplicates.  If the applicant_id are the same, but stages are different, they are ok, If the applicant_id's are the same and stages are either the same (biometrics & biometrics) or if it is (biometrics and biometrics_queue) I need to delete that entry from the array.

Not sure how to do this.
.

So here is what I have so far.  It works, but there are a lot of loops going on, don't wanna end up using too many resources or getting into an infinite loop...Does anyone see anything wrong with what I'm doing?
First, I used a function called convert stages, so that if there is anything that is a stage name and then _queue appended to the end, it changes it to just the stage name.

```
foreach ($timer_entry as $key => $value){
        $timer_entry[$key]['stage'] = convert_stages($timer_entry[$key]['stage']);
      }
```

Then I have a foreach inside of a for, checking for applicant_id's that might be the same:

```
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($timer_entry); $i++) {        
          foreach ($timer_entry as $key => $value){
            if ($key == $i) {
              continue;
            }
            else {
              if ($timer_entry[$key]['applicant_id'] == $timer_entry[$i]['applicant_id']) {
                if ($timer_entry[$key]['stage'] == $timer_entry[$i]['stage']) {
                  unset($timer_entry[$key]);
                }
              }
            }
        }
      }
```

If they are the same, I unset them.

Comment: do you only need to delete the duplicate? Or all occurences ?

Comment: Did I get it correctly that entries with duplicate `applicant_id`s but different `stage`s should be deleted?

Comment: @HaukeP. hmm, dunno, he says if stages are different, they are ok. But then he is like saying 'biometrics & biometrics_queue' are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but I think this might do the trick:

```
$array = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));
```

Comment: hmm. should work... (if the order of the element never changes)

Comment: That won't work as described in the question as I understand it. It won't delete duplicate `applicant_id`s with different `stage`s. Or did I get the question wrong?

Comment: @HaukeP. you're right. I'll try to come up with a better solution and edit my post.

Comment: @TerryHarvey no, the question states different stages is ok !

Comment: @nl-x I think so too. OP's wording is a little confusing.

Comment: I think I found what I need to do.  I was wanting to first check to see if there were duplicate applicant_id's if it was a duplicate, check to make sure it's not the same person in a different stage. If both the applicant_id's and the stages were the same, remove. If the stages were the same, but with '_queue' appended (biometrics = biometrics_queue, documentation = documentation_queue) these are to be removed as well.

Comment: @user3284694 so you have no question?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach( $myArray as $index => $element )
    if (isset($tmp[$element['applicant_id']][str_replace('_queue','',$element['stage'])])
        unset($myArray[$index]);
    else
        $tmp[$element['applicant_id']][str_replace('_queue','',$element['stage'])] = true;
```